# How can i get the user input as the URL for another screen?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to obtain the user input from the first page and then pass to the second page to call the API. However it returns that 'only static members can be accessed in initializers'. Can anyone help?

my code is as following

```
String trackingnum = _trackingnumController.text;
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>new 
TrackingPage(trackingnum2: trackingnum)))
```

another screen

```
class TrackingPage extends StatefulWidget {
final String trackingnum2;
TrackingPage({Key key, @required this.trackingnum2}) : super(key: key);
 @override
 TrackingPageState createState() => TrackingPageState();
}

class TrackingPageState extends State<TrackingPage> {
 final url = urL + "/${widget.trackingnum2}";
```

Comment: try to remove `final`

Comment: I tried changing the final of both but the problem is still there. The word widget is underlined in red showing 'only static members can be accessed in initializers'.

Comment: The final is meant  to be there